# Hard drive not detected after replacing board

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage, hardware-detection

I have a 4TB WD “Elements” (WD Blue inside of the casing) Model: WD40NMZW-11GX681 portable drive that I use for my Xbox One. The drive has stopped working. When I plug it in nothing happens, it doesn’t sound like it spins up, and I don’t hear anything obviously going wrong inside.

I opened up the case and took a look inside, the USB port looked a little burned on the board (2060-800041-003 REV P1) so I found a replacement online and bought it. I have now replaced the board and when I plug the drive in it spins up and sounds good, but I cannot get it to be detected on my Xbox One or my Mac book pro. The drive doesn’t even show up unmounted in the disk utility list like it would with an incompatible format.

What is going on here? How can I get the drive to show up and work as normal? Preferably without losing my data, but it’s not the end of the world if I have to wipe it. Judging by the evidence was I incorrect in the diagnosis of the board/port being the issue?

Comment: So there is another chip on the OLD circuit board that contains the geometry of the drive and it has to be placed on the new board.

Comment: @cybernard can that be done with a soldering iron or would i need specialty tools?

Comment: As long as your careful it could probably be done with a soldering iron.